# How Can I Extract parameters from Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

Given a Stored procedure, I want to extract the parameter from it.

How can I do this in .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following SQL query in SQL Server 2005. You can of course call the same query using the `SqlCommand` class.

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.object_id,
    pm.parameter_id,
    pm.name AS parameter_name,
    pm.system_type_id AS parameter_system_type_id,
    pm.max_length AS parameter_max_length,
    t.name AS type_name
FROM sys.procedures p
JOIN sys.parameters pm ON p.object_id = pm.object_id
JOIN sys.types t ON pm.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE p.name = 'sprocName'
```

Of course, the `procedures`, `parameters` and `types` system views contain other interesting stored procedure and parameter information as well. This query is just a selection.

Comment: Argh - you beat me :-) Good answer !

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameter, which is Shared (VB.NET) or Static (C#) to which you pass the SqlCommand: [DeriveParameter on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx).
You just have to create a SqlCommand, setting the name of the stored procedure, call this method and look at the SqlCommand.Parameters property.